# Need help clarifying the function of an if statement

Tags: javascript, html

There's one piece of information I can't seem to find - what does `if(""!="")` do?

Here an example how it's used:

```
if(""!=""){document.write('<iframe src="'+''+'" border="0" alt="" style="display:none"/>');}
if(""!=""){document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+''+'"><\/scr'+'ipt>');}
```

Comment: taken out of context like that they seem to cause the `document.write` calls to not happen.  What are your observations?

Comment: It's equivalent to if(0), maybe it's a code that's supposed to not execute and be stored for copy/paste purpose?

Comment: Looks like someone left in code that should have been removed or commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a placeholder.

!= checks if the two things on both sides are not the same (opposite to ==).
`""!=""` would therefore always evaluate to false since the two empty strings are infact the same.

Thus the First line will never be called.

Comment: He mean `""!=""`, double quotes.